# Sitecore User Group Belarus - April 27, 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

Sitecore Community in Belarus is welcome to join us for the 5th Sitecore User Group Meetup in Minsk. The meetup will be held on April 27th (Thurday) at 19:00  (UTC 16:00) in Crowne Plaza Minsk, located at Kirava 13.

https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Belarus/events/238981919/

Agenda:

**Rob Habraken** - Technical Manager, Consultant & Sitecore MVP at Colours (Netherlands).  Specialist in web development, Microsoft technology and, of course, Sitecore. Noticed for his contributions to the community with topics on Azure, Rob is one of 10 Cloud experts worldwide to be named a Sitecore MVP Cloud 2017.

*"Azure Blue Green Deployments"*

**Anton Kuryan** - DevOps at Colours. Started with Sitecore back in 2010, focused on automation of everything. MCPS and MCSA, Anton works most of the time currently with Azure.

*“Continuous Integration for Sitecore”*

**Denis Busel** - Lead Sitecore/.NET Developer at Brimit. Denis is a Certified Sitecore developer, MCTS and MCP, has been working with Sitecore sine 2008.  Besides being professional in Sitecore, Denis is a goalkeeper in professional Hockey team.

*“An introduction to Score”*

Along with these topics we expect lots of networking supported with refreshing beverages.

RSVP for the meetup and stay tuned for updates on location and agenda!

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins on Apr 17 at 16:00